# Question about drives (Partition does not start on physical sector boundary)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have been reading this site quite a bit getting my first ever Ubuntu box running and had a question,

Currently my drive has partitions showing like this

```
   /dev/sda1   *        2048    31459327    15728640   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
   /dev/sda2        31459328    31664127      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
   /dev/sda3        31664128   656826936   312581404+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
   /dev/sda4       656828414   976771071   159971329    5  Extended
   Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
   /dev/sda5       656828416   971048959   157110272   83  Linux
   /dev/sda6       971051008   976771071     2860032   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I believe sda1 is Acer recovery disk or something, sda2 is the one I have been using to boot Windows and sda3 seems to be my main Windows storage drive.

I am wondering what is going on with sda4. It appeared like that after I had to re-install Ubuntu (I messed my first install up trying to get Acer wireless to work).

Should I worry about this? Everything runs fine so far in both Ubuntu and Windows. If I just ignore it, could anything happen?

I am dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

I should also note, just before I installed Ubuntu I had to do a recovery/repair of Windows 7. It wouldn't even load past the boot screen so I did a repair from the Windows cd. Not sure that affects anything.

Thanks